# asp:treeview expand when page visited

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp:treeview in my website where the selected node does not expand when the node the page links to is visited. You can see the problem here:

http://www.meronymy.com/SPARQL-Database-Server/Documentation/architecture/query-processor/query-parser.aspx

As you can see, the "Query parser" node is not shown in the menu even though the page that it links to is open, if you expand its parent, "Query processor", it is shown.

I only want the first level being expanded by default, the other levels should be collapsed unless a page that a subnode links to is visited.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="siteMapDataSource" ShowStartingNode="false" />
    <asp:TreeView ID="mnuTreeView" SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" ExpandDepth="1" DataSourceID="siteMapDataSource" 
        CssClass="treeview" ShowLines="true" ShowCheckBoxes="None" ShowExpandCollapse="True" SkipLinkText="" Runat="server">

        <LevelStyles>
            <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="10" 
                Font-Size="1.2em"/>
            <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="8" 
                Font-Size="1em"/>
            <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="6" 
                Font-Size="0.9em"/>
            <asp:TreeNodeStyle ChildNodesPadding="5" 
                Font-Size="0.8em"/>
        </LevelStyles>

    </asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no replies I'm guessing I will have to add my own code to traverse all the nodes in the asp:treeview and expand the node if the current page matches the page that the node links to.